# SQL Query Runs Forever

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
SELECT * 
FROM PaymentBatchItems
WHERE CreatedDate = '2016-11-03';
```

This query should return about 6 rows.  I have watched it run for over 7 minutes and still running.  I suspect there may be some inconsistent data in there, however I can't query the table to find out.

I ran

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE(PaymentBatchItems) WITH PHYSICAL_ONLY
```

and it returned no errors. Also tried

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE(PaymentBatchItems)
```

and it also returned no errors.

Any ideas how I can find what's hanging up my very simple query?

Comment: Network problem?  Humongous sql table with no index on CreatedData?

Comment: How many rows are there, is there any index, and what is the data type of that column?

Comment: How big is the table? Is there anything else running on the instance? Did you check the execution plan? Is the table properly indexed? Did you run `sp_who` to see if there are any deadlocks?

Comment: This table is not large... maybe 5000 rows at most.  The query I was running should only return a handful of rows. Nothing else is running on the instance as this is the test environment and I am the only developer.

Answer (score 4):

FOUND THE ISSUE!

When I was closing out my tabs at the end of the day, I discovered there were uncommitted transactions on one of the other server tabs.  Rolled back the transactions and was able to query the table without issue.

Thanks everyone for your help.  Sorry for the newbie error!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the table structure, most likely PaymentBatchItems has a varbinary/blob column which might contain a lot of data. Instead of returning * try to return only one column.

Also use "top" for example

select top(100) * from ...

Comment: Whether I use SELECT * or select just a single column, the query still hangs just the same.  Also tried using top 100 * and top 100 with a single column and got same results... query just runs and runs and runs.